# Develop a java program on as400 to create xml file from db2

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange, mainframe

I have some experience with java ee development and some web applications.
Now I have to create a java program on AS400, one I have never heard before.  Program is to create xml file from db2.

Do you have any idea how I should approach the development with no knowledge of AS400 and DB2?

I do appreciate any kind of suggestions and help!!!

Comment: I suggest a training on AS/400 respective coding for AS/400. Those IBM machines and DB/2 are somewhat "special" ...

Comment: @Fildor Thank a lot.  I will try one.  If you have any good resource, please let me know...

Comment: Data from AS/400 can be extracted in a few ways. If there is DB2 , these can be enabled for querying directly which you can do from JAVA , you could use a Messaging middleware (MQ Series / WMQ) to fetch this information. You could look at batches of file transfers for exchanging data as well. The answer and solutions are extremely subjective any of these or their combinations can work

Comment: There should be many and varied ways that you can access the data from DB2/400 without you having to know anything about OS/400 or DB2 (beyond any SQL differences, IBM provides online documentation which you can readily consult. You can start from the IBM Knowledge Center, or just hit it from a search). You need to talk to your people who do know about the AS/400/iSeries installation you want to use, and find out what is licensed to be used, and how they'd like you to do it. Just jamming in suggestions from a very broad question on the internet isn't the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: Create a folder to hold the java and have at it.

Comment: There should be an admin type of staff person who can create your basic user setup and get you started. If you need path or other settings specific to your site, the admin should also be able to provide details. In general, you should be able to approach the task just as you would for any other server with a DBMS. There shouldn't be anything you'll run into that you don't already know or that an admin can't provide.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!!

Comment: @user2338816 Yes, I will get some help from admin staff person.  I am now trying to get knowledge about AS400 and DB2 before admin's help...  I do appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in general, Java, on IBM i (previously known as AS/400), is java ... and DB2 is accessed via JDBC... so there isn't a whole lot different to consider.

You'll want to get the [JT400](http://jt400.sf.net) library for a JDBC driver.  Javadocs for JT400 can be found [here](http://javadoc.midrange.com).

If you have specific questions, or run into problems, consider subscribing to the [JAVA400-L](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/java400-l) mailing list.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  You have saved my days!!

Comment: This seems to be a good topic for the new Documentation section as it covers a relatively broad topic.